# Overloading Methods in Java with generics

Tags: java, overloading

I wanted to know if it is possible to overload a method by differing in the generic parameter. Example:

```
class Foo <T> { ... }

class Bar {
  public void do (Foo<Integer> obj) {}
  public void do (Foo<Double> obj) {}
}
```

I know this will not be compiled. But for example in kotlin you have the annotation JvmName where you can annotate these methods to get compiled the code. Do Java has this possibility, too?

Comment: No. Type erasure. `Foo<Anything>` becomes `Foo<Object>`, because it must.

Comment: The correct way to handle this would be handling a `Foo<Number>` and differentiating the type within the method if necessary.

Comment: No, this is not possible in java. From the annotation I would suspect that the annotation renames the method in the bytecode, thus making the calls unambiguous. I would recommend to renaming the methods, so that their names are different from each other.

Comment: Java generics are flawed and are not nearly as robust as those used in C#.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that's the price of backwards compatibility. C# didn't have to make that choice.

Comment: @Kayaman agree. So now we're stuck with good: compile-time type safety checking; and bad: type erasure with its resulting lack of generic run-time functionality

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels not to mention Oracle behind there, always ready to stir up trouble.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels [maybe, maybe, maybe (reified generics)](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/valhalla/Main)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have two methods with the same erasure in the same type. That said, you may be able to manipulate the erasure retaining the same type. For instance, if `Foo` was an interface:

```
interface Foo<T> { /* ... */ }

class Bar {
    public void do_(Foo<Integer> obj) { }
    public <A extends Object & Foo<Double>> void do_(A obj) { }
}
```

But, **avoid overloading methods** even where generics are not involved.

Comment: So, it's not good overloading methods for a Visitor Design Pattern in order to have double-dispatch?

Comment: Mind elaborating on your last remark? I'd think method overloading is one key (and useful) feature of languages like Java...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Visitor pattern? Yeah, use meaningful names as you would in a dynamically-typed language. It has the benefit that it means it's not necessarily necessary to be fixed to the types of one representation of the hierarchy being traversed.